# Laravel primaryKey override Ignored - Query returning unknown column error

Tags: php, laravel, primary-key, laravel-5.5

I'm working with a database where id column is named user_id.

I've set the $primaryKey override in the user model but it's still looking for `id`. It appears when the user model extends Authenticatable, it's ignored. Authenticatable extends modal, so shouldn't be an issue, right?

I've seen plenty of threads where primaryKey override isn't working, but nothing has helped.

Error when accessing User:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `members` where `email` = user@gmail.com and `id` <> 1804)
```

User Model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'members';

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

Update producing error:

```
public function rules()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return [
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'email',
            Rule::unique($user->getTable())->ignore($user->getKey()),
        ],
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

DB Column:

```
Name | Type  |  Attributes  | Null | Extra 
user_id (PrimaryKey) | int(60) | Unsigned | No | AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Please show the code that generates the error.

Comment: Can we see the `column type` from the database?

Comment: @Klav I don't think the query you've shown is generating this SQL `select count(*) as aggregate from members where email = user@gmail.com and id <> 1804`

Comment: Ahh you are right, looks like it's the validation -- only other thing there. Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sql statement looks like something the unique validation rule would generate. It has a syntax to specify the primary key if it isn't `id`.

> If your table uses a primary key column name other than id, you may specify the name of the column when calling the ignore method:
>
> ```
> 'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id')
> ```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique, under the paragraph "Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID".

Comment: It's funny how you did post the answer with OP's validation code 1 minute before OP added the validation code to his question.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. So I need to add this unique rule everywhere rules are used for this table?